# HTML refresh button

Tags: html

```html
<input onclick="window.location.reload( false )" type="button" value="New Stair">
```

When I run this from edge, the page refreshes.
When I run it from FireFox, the page clears all and I have to press the web refresh or F5 for the sheet to refresh.

Here is the full code.

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0049)file://S:\Stairs\Stair Tracker\Headroom Calc.html -->
<!-- Generated by F12 developer tools. This might not be an accurate representation of the original source file -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Bump My Head?</title>


<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
                text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>


</head><body>

  <label for="text1">Total Height:
    <input name="text1" id="hgt" type="text" size="7" maxLength="7" value="" onchange="calcrise()";>
  </label>
  <label for="text2">Total Travel:
    <input name="text2" id="tvl" type="text" size="6" maxLength="6" value="">
  </label><label for="text3"><br>
    Floor Depth:
    <input name="text2" id="bm" type="text" size="6" maxLength="6" value="">
  </label>
  <label for="text4">Headroom:
    <input name="text4" id="hdr" type="text" size="6" maxLength="6" value="">
  </label>
  <label for="text5">Number of rises:
    <input name="text5" id="rises" type="text" size="2" maxLength="2" value="">
  </label>
    <label for="text6">Rise:
    <input name="text6" id="rise" type="text" size="5" maxLength="5" value="">
  </label>
  &nbsp;<input onclick="calc()" type="button" value="Draw">
  <input onclick="window.location.reload( false )" type="button" value="New Stair">
  <br>
  <p>Enter Total Height from floor to floor</p>
    <p>Floor depth includes <span class="style1">Top of floor to bottom of 
    Beam/Joist</span></p>
<p>Click new stair to delete the current stair drawing, and change the numbers 
again to calculate a new stair.</p>
<p>If the total rise is Less than the Floor depth and headroom requirement, 
the headroom line may not appear in the image.</p>
   <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas" style="border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);">
    <br>Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function calcrise()  {
var hgt= parseFloat(document.getElementById("hgt").value);
  var h=Math.ceil(hgt/8);
  var r=hgt/h;
  document.getElementById("rises").value=h;
    document.getElementById("rise").value=r;

  }
    function calc() {
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var rs = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rise").value);
      var tvl = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tvl").value);
      var lp = parseInt(document.getElementById("rises").value);
      var rn=tvl/(lp-1);
      var x = 500 / (lp * rn);
      ctx.scale(x, x);
   var max = lp; // how many times

      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

      for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {

        ctx.lineTo(rn * (i - 1), rs * i);
        ctx.lineTo(rn * i, rs * i);
      }      ctx.lineTo(rn * lp, rs * lp);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
      ctx.stroke();
      var htx = c.getContext("2d");
      var bm = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bm").value);
      var h3 = 3;
      var hdr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hdr").value);
      var h1 = ((bm + hdr) / rs * rn);
      var numb = h1;
      numb = numb.toFixed(2);
      var s = "The minimum opening is "
      var s1 = " Inches"
      var txt = s + numb + s1
      htx.rect(h1, 0, h3, bm);
      htx.stroke();
      ctx.lineTo(h1, hdr);
      ctx.lineTo(h1, hdr + bm);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.font = "4px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(txt, rn, 5);
      //alert(h1)
    }
  </script>



</body></html>
```

Comment: The question is?

Comment: It works well in Edge but fails in Firefox.

Comment: According to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) It might throw an `DOMException` preventing its completion. Not sure how you would `catch` that `exception` inside the `onclick` attribute

Comment: The example refresh button seems to work fine on latest firefox, chrome and edge. I could not reproduce the problem with that `input` element

Comment: Interesting. FireFox and Chrome, it just disappears and I have to refresh the page for it to come back.

Comment: Can you use something to log into console to see how it behaves? ie. add something to log to console at the beginning of script? I tried with setInterval to see how it refreshed scripts.

Comment: I tried the full code and only thing console gives "error" for is for the character set not being defined after `<!DOCTYPE html>` it reloads the page just fine locally.

Comment: The code does work fine it I run it from firefox from my local computer, but when out in the world it doesn't work as well. Everything else works, just the refresh doesn't here is the link, I am using google sites.[HeadRoom Calc](https://sites.google.com/view/nufab-stairs/headroom-calculator)

Comment: here is a sample of the numbers to enter,height=121, travel=151,flrdepth=20,hdroom=80 then click draw

Comment: I noticed you run it through `<iframe>` it might be the reason firefox will throw the `DOMException`. iframe works a tad bit different from direct sites and security issues are often risen. Also noticed it's iframe inside iframe.

Comment: Wont work for me in either edge nor firefox.

Comment: No change is reflected to the functionality of the button when I change the html of the button so there's really no way of testing it through that site or the html doesn't represent what function is really bound to that button. In my tests I tried to reload the parent page within 2 iframes and browser indeed threw a `DOMException` preventing such thing. In your case tho the `iframe` gets loaded that script somewhat confusingly.

Comment: So if your iframes are set up correctly the reload script was this: `window.parent.parent.location.reload()` since there was 2 iframes

Comment: Your original iframe tho is only a blank template which gets the script loaded in. It could be your problem. Refresh works as you'd say, but the script doesn't get reloaded inside of it.

Comment: So the blank page is the iframe which was refreshed, but the site which it displays is inserted into it somehow and it doesn't get called when refreshing the page. You could try the window.parent.reload() and window.parent.parent.reload() if the iframe allows it, but otherwise you would have to get the original iframe page generation working when you refresh it.

Comment: You have your page setup like this: `<iframe src...>htmlheadbody... <iframe src...><script>another onload event fired and some scripts ran</script></iframe><script>this fires onload event and updates inner iframe</script></iframe>` The outer iframe script doesn't get re-run after the inner iframe refreshes so you only get a blank page.

Comment: AH, thanks, little above my expertise on this. I just made the whole thing on Web Expressions many years ago as an office function, now I thought the same code would work on line.